# Outlook Subfolder Expansion

Tags: vba, outlook, expand

I've code to expand folders in Outlook. It works for the first level folders, but won't expand the subfolders (in this case the xx Progressions folder).

The code doesn't bug out: the subfolder simply does not expand.

```
Private Sub ExpandFolders()

Dim objCurrentFolder As Outlook.Folder
Dim objStore As Outlook.Store
Dim objFileFolders As Outlook.Folders
Dim objFolder As Outlook.Folder
Dim objView As Outlook.View

'Expand xx Notifications
Set objStore = Outlook.Application.Session.Stores("xxNotification")
Set objFileFolders = objStore.GetRootFolder.Folders
Set Application.ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder = objFileFolders("Inbox") 'Works fine

'Expand xx Delivery Support
Set objStore = Outlook.Application.Session.Stores("xxDeliverySupport")
Set objFileFolders = objStore.GetRootFolder.Folders
Set Application.ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder = objFileFolders("Inbox")
Set Application.ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder = objFileFolders("Inbox").Folders("xx Progressions") 'Does not expand

'User inbox
Set objStore = Outlook.Application.Session.Stores("xx.xx@xx.com")
Set objFileFolders = objStore.GetRootFolder.Folders
Set Application.ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder = objFileFolders("Inbox") 'Works fine

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You trick a folder into expanding by selecting a folder under it.

Step through the code to see the expansion is "delayed" by one folder.

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub ExpandFolders()

Dim objStore As store
Dim objFileFolders As folders
Dim objCurrentFolder As Folder

Set objStore = Session.Stores("xxDeliverySupport")

Set objFileFolders = objStore.GetRootFolder.folders

' expand "xxDeliverySupport" by selecting Inbox
Set ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder = objFileFolders("Inbox")

Set objCurrentFolder = ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder

' expand "Inbox" by selecting "xx Progressions"
Set ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder = objCurrentFolder.folders("xx Progressions")

Set objCurrentFolder = ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder

' expand "xx Progressions" by selecting folder one level below
Set ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder = objCurrentFolder.folders(1)

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks niton! This is really helpful. I've placed this code in application_startup and it works perfectly, except for a small problem: the last folder in the code is the one that is selected by default when Outlook starts (as you'd expect), but if I try to select another inbox, Outlook just springs back to this one. Does something need disabling or resetting at the end of the code? Thanks again.

Comment: No reason I can see for this behaviour. Put a breakpoint, perhaps application_startup is triggered by some other code.